# collision detection for multiple object at once

Tags: collision-detection, sfml, collision

im new to developing games, im trying out sfml implementation in Crystal programming language and im wondering about collision detection.
[Documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-transform.php) mentions method such as `contains` for points and `intersects` for boxes.

I have a basic understanding of how those work and I cant help but wonder how am i supposed detect collisions of multiple object at once. think of something like space invaders: do i need to manually check every shot on the screen with every potential target every time screen refreshes? it seems to be very exhausting and impractical when objects begin to pile up. Are there any common solutions to that problem?

Comment: For being new and having something as simple as space invaders that's perfectly fine. Basic collision detection is computationally simple. Unless you are going to have hundreds of enemies and bullets all on the screen at the same time it's unlikely it's going to cause any issues. Optimizing collisions detection is very much based on how the items move and the type of game that's being made.